# Will "Contacts" permission allow reading contacts list on SIM?

Tags: security, permissions

I denied "Contacts" perm of obvious reasons for an app. It won't work. I reached its developer and he said I am paranoid, that "Contacts" means just basic info about phone owner, like name and email, not contact list. But it says "Contacts", not "Basic owner info". Who is right? How to give app "Contacts" permission but hide contacts list from it?

Comment: What app are we talking about? The `Contacts` permission allows access to contacts, obviously. Finally, your phone sees all of the contacts, ergo something with that permission sees any contact the phone can see.

Answer (score 2):

> Who is right?

I think you are right because "Contacts" permission - [quote](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_CONTACTS):

> Allows an application to read the user's contacts data.

You can write an [abuse](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2853570?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en) to Google about this application if you think they use "Contacts" permission unreasonably and Google may check that application more accurately.